# Hibernate one to one allows many to one

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have created a unidirectional one-to-one relationship like this:

```
@Entity(name="person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "pid", unique = true) // note 2
    private int id;

    // more fields

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="address_id", unique = true) // note 1
    private Address address;

    // rest of class
}

@Entity(name="address")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "aid", unique = true)
    private int id;

    // rest of class
}
```

note 1:

If I don't specify the "address_id" column to be unique like this

```
   @JoinColumn(name="address_id")
```

then it is not unique and I can have many persons refer to the same adress which is a many-to-one relation like this:

```
Person person1 = new Person();
Person person2 = new Person();
Address address  = new Address("21th street");
person1.setAddress(address);
person2.setAddress(address);
```

Shouldn't a one-to-one relation make the foreign key "address_id" unique by default?

note 2:

The id is not unique although I specify it. Why?

Comment: Have you tried with Address having a personId in it that needs to be of type Person with a @OneToOne/@JoinColumn on it?

Comment: that wouldn't make it unidirectional.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate doesn't enforce the uniqueness. That's the job of the database.

For your OneToOne, make sure there is a unique constraint on the `address_id` column. For the IDs, make sure there is a primary key constraint (which enforces uniqueness) on the ID columns.

If you generate the database using Hibernate DDL generation, Hibernate will use the attributes of the annotations: `@Id` will create a PK, and `unique = true` will generate a unique constraint.

But for any serious work, I would generate the schema by myself, using a tool like FlywayDB or Liquibase, which allows migrating your schema from version to version.

Comment: My question is why doesn't hibernate enforce the uniqueness. Is the one-to-one annotation just a marker to define the relation? Also unique=true on the id does not make it unique.

Comment: Is there a PK contraint created for the ID? If there is one, then it is unique, because PKs are implicitely unique (otherwise, they would not be PKs). The answer from Billy Frost seems to indicate that Hibernate should generate a unique constraint for a OneToOne by default. It seems it doesn't. So, add unique = true, and it will, or define the schema by yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your time. So, is Hibernate DDL generator incomplete or is this on purpose?

Comment: I have no idea. Ask them.

Answer (score 0):

As per the JPA spec 2.10.3.1 there should be a unique constraint created by default

> Table A contains a foreign key to table B. The foreign key column name
>   is formed as the concatenation of the following: the name of the
>   relationship property or field of entity A; "_"; the name of the
>   primary key column in table B. The foreign key column has the same
>   type as the primary key of table B and there is a unique key
>   constraint on it.

So Hibernate seems to be contravening that part of the spec. I seem to remember that EclipseLink also does (or did) that. You should be able to find another question in Stackoverflow about it. DataNucleus did it right last I looked.